# How to make my Filter Pattern more generic

Tags: java

I've written some code which uses the filter design pattern like so:

```
public class SingleLengthCriteria implements XsamCriteria {

private final FilterLength filterLength;

public SingleLengthCriteria(FilterLength filterLength)  {
  this.filterLength = filterLength;
}

@Override
public List<XsamRecord> meetRecordCriteria(List<XsamRecord> records) {
  List<XsamRecord> spanLengthRecords = new ArrayList<>();

  for(XsamRecord record : records){
    if(record.getXs() >= filterLength.getMin() && record.getXs() <= filterLength.getMax()){
    spanLengthRecords.add(record);
    }
  }

  return spanLengthRecords;
}
```

The `FilterLength` is just a pojo with a min and max cooordinate.

The `XsamRecord` is the object which is being filtered. In this example, i'm filtering on the `XsamRecords` `getXs` method which simple returns an integer.

This all works well, but I'm also looking to create the same thing for other `getx...` methods (they also return integers). For example, I have `getxL`, `getxR`. Writing the same thing over and over for a different getter isn't exactly keeping things DRY.

Is there any way to pass the `get..` method into the constructor so that it knows which one to call in the `for` loop below?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to accept a `Function<XsamRecord, Integer> propertyValueGetter` and use that instead of hardcoding `.getXs` . In the constructor use `XsamRecord::getXs` etc.

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way, using method references. The syntax would be, for example, `XsamRecord::getXs`.

The type for the associated parameter would be `Function<XsamRecord, Integer>`.

```
public class SingleLengthCriteria implements XsamCriteria {

private final FilterLength filterLength;
private final Function<XsamRecord, Interger> propertyValueGetter;

public SingleLengthCriteria(FilterLength filterLength, Function<XsamRecord, Interger> propertyValueGetter)  {
  this.filterLength = filterLength;
  this.propertyValueGetter = propertyValueGetter;
}

@Override
public List<XsamRecord> meetRecordCriteria(List<XsamRecord> records) {
  List<XsamRecord> spanLengthRecords = new ArrayList<>();

  for(XsamRecord record : records){
    final Integer value = propertyValueGetter.apply(record);
    if(value >= filterLength.getMin() && value <= filterLength.getMax()){
    spanLengthRecords.add(record);
    }
  }

  return spanLengthRecords;
}
```

Used as:

```
new SingleLengthCriteria(..., XsamRecord::getXs);
new SingleLengthCriteria(..., XsamRecord::getOtherProperty);
```